# How to create a front end for Jhipster micro service

Tags: jhipster, angular2-nativescript, jhipster-registry

I have  successfully set up both jhipster microservice app and gateway app. 
Both are successfully talking to each other.

Now I am building a separate app (mobile app -  nativescript) , and am trying to make it talk to
How should I go about it? What all things I need to look its configuration ?
Pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

First, your mobile app must register through the gateway **/api/register** endpoint.

Second, it must retrieve it's token (if you use JWT) through the gateway **/api/authenticate** endpoint.

Last, it can then consume the microservice **/api/*** by adding Authorization to the HTTP request header :

```
Authorization: Bearer tokenRetrieved
```